# how to create virtual env in python programatically?

Tags: python, linux, virtual-environment

I looked up few documentation and utilizing venv package, i'm tyring to create a virtual environment programatically,then activate it and install libraries to run my script . however , when i try this (sample below) , in my mac, it doesn't work and i get error => bash: source ven/bin/activate: No such file or directory.

```
import os
import subprocess
import venv

v_name = "ven"

# Create the virtual environment
builder = venv.EnvBuilder(system_site_packages=False, clear=True, symlinks=False, upgrade=False, with_pip=True)
builder.create(v_name )

#activate
virtual_path = os.path.join(v_name , "bin", "activate")
subprocess.call([f"bash", f"source {virtual_path }"])
```